# Put JS and Jquery data into input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, geolocation

i found this function to get geolocation in JS

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert('Browser support geolocation')
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else { alert('Browser does not support geolocation'); }

    function showPosition(position) {

        alert(position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude);
        document.title = position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude;

    }
```

and this one to change value of one input text(in jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#local').attr('value',c);
  });
});
```

now, how can i put (position.coords.latitude) and (position.coords.longitude) into input text(#local)

thanks already, this will save my job haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    $('#local').val(position.coords.latitude + ' : ' +  position.coords.longitude);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    alert('Browser does not support geolocation');
}
```

### DEMO

Answer (score 0):

```
  function showPosition(position) {

     $('#local').attr('value',position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include jquery framework and then:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    $('#local').attr('value',position.coords.latitude + ":" + position.coords.longitude);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        alert('Browser support geolocation')
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     }
     else { 
         alert('Browser does not support geolocation'); 
     }
});
```